# undefined method 'id' for #<Page::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f4723af2208>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have no idea what is going on with a query I am doing in Rails console.  I am running Rails 4.1.5. First I get a group of items:

pages = Item.item_steps.map {|item| item.pages }

Once I have these pages, I then find out the class:

```
pages.class
#array
```

So, I now have an array.  Easy enough as I know a ton of methods that you can run on an array.  However, when I do any valid array method on the pages array it doesn't work.  For example:

```
pages.map(&:id)
NoMethodError: undefined method `domain_id' for #<Page::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f4723af2208>
```

or

```
irb(main):090:0> pages.pluck("id")
NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x007f4725681640>
```

I just want to get the "id" from the pages array, but nothing I know of works with this.

thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully through the errors, I think you would see what the issue is. Your current query produces the following type of result:

```
[ACollectionOfPages, ACollectionOfPages, ...]
```

So your `map` code is trying to call `#id` on an `ActiveRecord` collection, because that is what each element of your array is.

If you really want to use your current code, I'd run:

```
pages.map { |collection| collection.map(&:id) } # possibly with .flatten
```

You would be better of creating an association like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_steps
  has_many :pages, through: :item_steps
end
```

Then, `Item.pages` will return an `ActiveRecord` collection, so you could run `Item.pages.pluck(:id)`.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  I will update the model as well.  I inherited this application and having been using Rails 4 that long.  This collectionproxy that is new in rails 4 is tripping me up.